# Dynamic menu using database

Tags: c#, sql, authentication, menu

I have a database, which has three tables:

1. **login**

   ```
   userName
   password
   uId
   roleId
   ```
2. **path**

   ```
   pathId
   pathUrl
   pathName
   pathDetails
   roleId
   ```
3. **role**

   ```
   roleId
   roleName
   ```

I want to show path according to role ID. I mean I want to make dynamic menu according to login of a user. How can I do this according to given tables?

I thought about retrieving `pathUrl` and `pathName` according to `roleId` and binding it to a menu control, but I don’t know which ASP.net control will be suitable for this. It should bind `pathUrl` as back and `pathName` as display hyperlink. The query should be:

```
SELECT pathId, pathUrl, pathDetails
FROM path
WHERE roleId={role id of a logged user will be here}
```

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: just table and a query

Comment: you need to post that code for us to see what you have done so far.

Comment: So what is the thing that is not clear? How to use [ASP.net Menu control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ecs0x9w5.aspx)? Just get the menu structure from the database, create [MenuItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menuitem.aspx) instances and add them to `Items` collection of the menu (`menu.Item.Add(menuItem)`). Look at the example code in [`Menu` constructor documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.menu.aspx).